# Show modal onchange of FileUpload control

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this FileUpload control with some JS in the onchange property that gets a confirmation before posting back. It works great.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadTxReciept" runat="server" hidden onchange="if (confirm('Upload ' + this.value + '?')) this.form.submit();" />
```

I'm trying to convert this to a Bootstrap modal confimation popup, but its just not firing for some reason.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadTxReciept" runat="server" hidden CssClass="fileUploadModal"/>
```

...

```
$('.fileUploadModal').change(function () {
    $('#confirm-delete').modal({
        show: 'true'
    });
});
```

Any assist would be much appreciated. Thx

Comment: can you try $('#confirm-delete').modal('show') (copied from the bootstrap website)

Comment: That did not make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: @Nugs Is there any error you get in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ( data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ) attributes in html. See example :-

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

Hope it helps ;-)